# retrieve form valid state in an ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form that I create using an `ng-include`. I'm trying to retrieve it's state outside the scope of the `ng-include`. What is the best way to watch the value of `userForm.$valid` in  the child scope ? Is it possible to bind `userForm.$valid` to a variable in the parent scope in`mainController` ?

a simplified version of the problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/usiAINdotGkvwiYwnBhl?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine when we pass properties from parent to a child component to be used as **child component's properties** because the child component **has no knowledge** about its parent like we normally do when we pass parent's scope properties to a reusable directive (with isolate scope).

Your case is opposite, you need to update a parent property inside a child component. In general, a component should not have any knowledge about its parent, otherwise, there will be a **tight coupling**.

In your case, I suggest a solution using event-driven, whenever the validity changes, the form will dispatch an event, any other components subscribed to the event will be notified

With your code, create a controller on the form:

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="formController" novalidate>
```

Your js code:

```
// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on("formValidityChanged",function(event,validity){ //your main controller is interested in the event, listen to it
        $scope.userFormValidity = validity;
    });
});

// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('formController', function($scope) {
   $scope.$watch("userForm.$valid",function(value){
      $scope.$emit("formValidityChanged",value);
   })
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/lcbIUeptz68OEx2GBp3L?p=info)